# Making a POST to a folder are recived as a GET

Tags: apache, .htaccess, post, request

I'm making an api in php without using a framework and when I send a POST using postman to a folder the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` on index.php is a GET.

Example of my folder organization:

```
api
 ┗ engine
    ┗ index.php
    ┗ history.php
```

If i make a POST to

```
http://localhost/project/api/engine
```

the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` on index.php is GET, but if i make a POST to

```
http://localhost/project/api/engine/
```

(additional slash at end) the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` is POST

I tried to create a .htaccess with some rules provided by chatgpt (because I don't know anything about .htaccess) but nothing worked

How can i make the POST be a POST when i request the folder without the slash at the end?

My environment : 
Windows 11 
XAMPP as server 
PHP 8.2.4

Comment: There is probably a 301 or 302 redirect happening, and a POST request that gets a redirect becomes a GET as defined in the HTTP spec. The solution is simply "do not POST to a URI that incurs a redirect", as well as "do not configure redirects in your API paths".

Comment: As PHP is not relevant to this question I would suggest replacing the PHP tag with the Apache tag, and posting the relevant .htaccess config so that your question can be properly answered.

Comment: You would have to set [`DirectorySlash`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) to `off`, but before you do, pay attention to the security warning there in the documentation.

Comment: @CBroe Setting `DirectorySlash Off` is not enough, as the trailing slash is _required_ in order to serve the `DirectoryIndex` from that directory (which is what the OP is expecting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Apache mod_dir appends the trailing slash to the physical directory in order to "fix"<sup>***1**</sup> the URL. This is achieved with a 301 (permanent) redirect. The "problem" here is that a 301 (and 302) tends to get converted to a `GET` request by the user-agent/browser on the redirected (2nd) request. And this naturally loses the POST data. (*Aside:* A 307 and 308 were created to resolve this issue as they *preserve* the request method through the redirect. Although, it goes without saying, you should never be linking/requesting a URL that redirects in the first place.)

Requests to `/project/api/engine/` directly "work" because no 301 redirect occurs.

<sup>***1**</sup> The trailing slash is *required* in order to serve the `DirectoryIndex` document (ie. `index.php`) from that directory (which is what you are expecting).

You can prevent mod_dir from appending the trailing slash with the `DirectorySlash Off` directive. However, you still need to manually append the trailing slash (with an internal rewrite), otherwise your `DirectoryIndex` document (`index.php`) is not going to be served. You also need to ensure that auto-generated directory listings (mod_autoindex) are disabled, otherwise a directory listing will be returned in the response even if a `DirectoryIndex` document is present in that directory.

So, you could do it like this in the `/project/api/.htaccess` file (so as to restrict the directories affected):

```
# /project/api/.htaccess

# Disable auto generated directory listings (mod_autoindex)
Options -Indexes

# Prevent mod_dir appending a trailing slash to directories
DirectorySlash Off

# Need to use mod_rewrite ...
RewriteEngine On

# Internally append the trailing slash to directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ [L]
```

Note that you will need to clear any local caches since 301 (permanent) redirects are generally cached by default.

---

#### Alternative - Change your file structure

HOWEVER, I would avoid disabling `DirectorySlash` as this could result in additional issues depending on your system. And using a non-descriptive `index.php` file is not recommended anyway. Instead I would rethink your file structure a little and perhaps just remove the `.php` extension from your requests.

For example, the file structure could be like the following instead:

```
project
  ┗ api
     ┗ engine.php
     ┗ history.php
```

Your API requests would then be of the form `/project/api/engine` (and `/project/api/history` as opposed to `/project/api/engine/history.php`).

In your `/project/api/.htaccess` you just need some code to append the `.php` extension via an internal rewrite. For example:

```
# /project/api/.htaccess

# Need to use mod_rewrite ...
RewriteEngine On

# Append the ".php" file extension where necessary:
RewriteCond $1 !(\.php|/)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

Optionally, you could also block any direct requests to the `.php` files themselves.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I'll make the changes you recommended <3